# What is the best way to suggest a new feature for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

So far I have been suggesting new features to http://delphi.uservoice.com

Since it is managed by Nick Hodges (who is no longer an employee of Embarcadero) I decided to report my future improvements requests to http://qc.embarcadero.com

Is QC this the right way to go or is there a dedecated Idea Share solution I am not aware of?

Just as a reference I will point one of my suggestions [Add Patterns.pas to allow easily document code](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=102417)

Please advise which is best place to submit such stuff to?

[image: Sample Report]

Comment: Are you sure your sample request is related to the `TStringGrid`?

Comment: Well, I am not a regular visitor to Embarcadero's QC, but seeing as they have got a dedicated report type, *New Feature Request*, I'd expect that site to be the right place for requests of this kind.

Comment: I still don't get why my questions got closed. In the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq it says "What kind of questions can I ask here? your question generally cover software tools commonly used by programmers". I do consder Delphi as the most on-topic software tool used by Delphi programmers. Please advice.

Comment: @Andreas No idea what TStringGrid you refer to?

Comment: @Gad D Lord: You posted your request in the 'Delphi-BCB/VCL/Additional Controls/TStringGrid' category...

Comment: @Abdreas - It is reported in the Delphi-BCB/RTL/Delphi section as per attached screenshot. I believe it is the right section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QC is the only official place for end users to report bugs or make suggestions. While alternatives like uservoice might be nice I'm not aware of any Embarcadero employees actively monitoring that site.

Comment: The old [QualityCentral](http://qc.embarcadero.com) was replaced with [Quality Portal](http://quality.embarcadero.com) several years ago. Also note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).